# How to install ruby-devel and python-devel in SuSE Enterprise?

Tags: software-installation, suse, sles

I've been trying to install some software in SuSE Enterprise (SLES 11 SP 2 64 bits), and keep getting errors about missing dependencies. In the past, I could work around them (in an Ubuntu system) by installing **python-devel**, but I couldn't find it in SLES repository. Now I need to install Ruby Gems, and also can't find either **ruby-devel** or **rubygems** using zypper.

I should be able to [install Gems manually](http://heatware.net/ruby-rails/how-to-install-rubygems-linux-ubuntu-10/), but I'm clueless about those two "devel" packages. When googling them, I keep getting OpenSuse results (which are pointless, since AFAIK OpenSuse comes with these packages already included in its repositories) regardless of searching for "suse", "suse enterprise" or "sles". Most searches for binaries also show only files targeting OpenSuse.

How can I install these two packages? I'm fairly new to SuSE Enterprise (or SuSE in general), and not very familiar to its installation procedures. I've had no problems using zypper or YaST to install things which came included in the default repositories, but - while I could look up how to include other repos - I'm having trouble even *finding* the right ones to include.

P.S. I just found [this thread](https://forums.suse.com/archive/index.php/t-864.html) about [the lack of] devel RPMs for SuSE Enterprise. I haven't tried following those instructions yet (will do later, if a more direct and/or simpler approach doesn't show up).

Comment: try this -> http://rpm.pbone.net .. Select option, "advanced RPM Search", Select your distribution their.

Comment: @Tejas nope, selected "SuSE 11.X" and searched for "ruby-devel" and "python-devel". In both cases, nothing was found...

Answer (score 2):

As with most devel-packages for SLES, python-devel and ruby-devel are not included in SLES itself but can be found in the **SLES Software Development Kit (SDK)**.

Download the [SLES 11 SP2 SDK ISO](https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=NgW3ToaagDQ~) and add it as a repository to install the packages with zypper.

Newer versions of the SDK can be found on [download.suse.com](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SLE-SDK/11-SP2/).